# single RequireJS optimizer file for multiple directory project

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs

I'm wondering if it's possible to configure the RequireJS optimizer to fit with our current project structure.

The site directory is structured as below...

- root

  - project1

    - scripts

      - main.js
      - main.min.js
  - project2

    - scripts

      - main.js
      - main.min.js
  - project3

    - scripts

      - main.js
      - main.min.js

I was wondering if it's possible to have a "main" file sitting at the root level that will optimize all the child project main.js files and place them within their respective directories.  I noticed the multi-page optimizer example on the Requirejs homepage but i'm unsure how to configure that to work for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just one main.js file per project? I think when I used require js modules, it optimized with this behavior, but in a separate build/distribution directory

see
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2404-Compiling-Optimizing-A-Subset-Of-A-RequireJS-Application.htm

Comment: Each project has a main file and also it's dependent modules.

Most of the articles or documentation I've read regarding optimizing multi-page sites output to a single output directory.  For this project structure, each outputted file will need to be exported next to the unminified main file.